# Have start menu index applications in places other than program files?

Tags: windows-7, search, file-management, start-menu, productivity

I love the ability to type any phrase into the start menu, and Windows 7 will bring up relevant executables under Program Files.

However, I have a separate folder of my own where I store several portable applications - usually small apps that run straight out of an unzipped folder with little dependency. I have all of these under a specific hard-coded location - "PortableApps", but I would really like to tell the start menu to search this folder as well as Program Files for executables when searching. The search is often clogged because the executables I'm looking for are classified under "Documents" in the search results and buried in other non-related files.

Is there a way I can achieve this in Windows 7?

Thanks for any suggestions
- Chase

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `mklink` to create a symlink to a given folder from the Start Menu.  Your best bet is to just create shortcuts for the apps and file them away in your user's start menu.

Comment: @user74757 Side tip suggestion, Auto hide toolbars, productive :-) start menu and search not as productive.